# scrollTargetLayout does not center views it targets

Tags: swiftui, scroll

I am working on a carousel view that snaps the pills to the center. I have laid out the following class and it somewhat works except a few things aren't behaving well.

```
struct AccountCarousel: View {
    
    struct AccountPill: View {
        @State var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(text)
            }.frame(width: 110, height: 80)
                .background(.red)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .scrollTransition { view, transition in
                    view.opacity(transition.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.3)
                }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer().frame(minWidth: 110, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .frame(width: 110)
                .background(.purple)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                        AccountPill(text: "\(i)")
                    }
                }.scrollTargetLayout()
            }.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                .defaultScrollAnchor(.center)
                .safeAreaPadding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                .background(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

There are a few issues happening I would love to adjust.

1. As you can see the scroll does not center the item. It's always a bit off.
2. The edge pills cannot scroll to center.
3. I would like the fade out effect to trigger a bit later than it currently does (which is right at the edge)

I have played with insets, fake objects, etc and have not been able to change any of these things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on `AccountPill`. You're setting the scroll behavior to `.viewAligned`. However, you're ignoring `HStack spacing` too. Re-calculate the `AccountPill` to fit, i.e, 1/3 screen's width, then it should work.

Steps: nested inside HStack with center alignment. Make 2 dummies leading and trailing `Spacer` to align `pill view`.

Updated for (3): use `.threshold(.visible)` for scroll transition. Threshold defines whether pill view is deemed visible based on how much it intersects with scroll view, such as: `.threshold(.visible(0.3))`. The pill view will be considered fully visible when it got 30% within scroll area.

```swift
struct AccountCarousel: View {
    
    var pillWidth: CGFloat {
        UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3
    }
    
    struct AccountPill: View {
        
        let size: CGFloat
        
        @State var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 10)
                
                VStack {
                    Text(text)
                }
                //width have to minus both Spacer's width to align to center.
                .frame(width: size - 20, height: 80)
                .background(.red)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .scrollTransition(.animated.threshold(.visible(0.3))) { view, transition in
                    view.opacity(transition.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.3)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 10)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer().frame(minWidth: pillWidth, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .frame(width: pillWidth)
                .background(.purple)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) { // <- Reduce to 0
                    ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                        AccountPill(size: pillWidth, text: "\(i)")
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                .defaultScrollAnchor(.center)
                .background(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works better. This solution does not center the pills if pillWidth is something like `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3` so something else is still afoot.

Comment: I thought the output above was your purpose. Can you explain about `Does not center the pills`? Actually, when scrolling, each pill will display at the center, like paging, right?

Comment: Yeah. That is the goal. I would like to be able to increase the space between the pills and not have it stop scrolling them to center.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, Can you provide an example of your idea?

Answer (score 0):

just add
.defaultScrollAnchor(.center)
to your ScrollView